# Does gtk_tree_store_remove free G_TYPE_BOXED values?

Tags: gtk3

If I create a new gtk_tree_store:
model= gtk_tree_store_new (1,G_TYPE_BYTE_ARRAY);

Add a value:
data=g_byte_array_new();
gtk_tree_store_set(GTK_TREE_STORE(model),iter,0,data,-1);

is the array freed when i call gtk_tree_store_remove()?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GtkTreeStore manages its own ref to whatever you give it. This means gtk_tree_store_set() adds a ref [1] and gtk_tree_store_remove() removes a ref [2].

Note the docs from gtk_tree_store_set [3]:

> The value will be referenced by the store if it is a G_TYPE_OBJECT, and it will be copied if it is a G_TYPE_STRING or G_TYPE_BOXED.

The fundamental type of G_TYPE_BYTE_ARRAY is G_TYPE_BOXED. In terms of the noted boxed **copy**, this is actually a ref of the byte array [4].

You still need to manage the ref you own from the result of g_byte_array_new(). So after gtk_tree_store_set(), the ref count of the byte array will be 2. Unless you are storing the byte array somewhere besides the tree store, you should free this ref **after** the call to gtk_tree_store_set(), otherwise you will leak a ref:

```c
data = g_byte_array_new ();
gtk_tree_store_set (GTK_TREE_STORE(model), iter, 0, data, -1);
g_byte_array_unref (data);
```

1. https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktreedatalist.c?id=3.13.3#n245
2. https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktreedatalist.c?id=3.13.3#n38
3. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeStore.html#gtk-tree-store-set
4. https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gobject/gboxed.c?id=2.41.1#n139